# How to display Hugo categories used to create list

Tags: hugo

In my Hugo list.html page that is accessed when a user clicks on a category, I'd like the user to be able to see which category they clicked on by displaying it.

I've tried the following code which I think is attempting to get it from the URL:

```
{{ range .Params.categories }}
    <a href="{{ "/categories/" | relLangURL }}{{ . | urlize }}">{{ . }}</a> 
{{ end }}
```

And my config.toml includes the relevant lines:

```
[taxonomies]
    tag = "tags"
    category = "categories"
```

Presently, nothing is displayed, and no 'a' tags are generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `.Title` is what you are looking for.

When an individual taxonomy term page is being generated, the variable `.Title` will be set to the current term (that is the actual tag or category).

When the list taxonomy page itself is being generated, it is set to the name  of the taxonomy (e.g. `tags`).

This is different from .Site.Title which is set in the `config.toml` file.

This is also different from `.Title` for an individual post which is set from the file's front matter.

So, the following snippet from my website :

```
<title>{{ .Site.Title }} {{ with .Title }} | {{ . }}{{ end }}</title>
```

Works equally well for any kind of page since `.Title` will be automatically set as appropriate for the page type.